# Excel VBA - Find Function - Find a variable

Tags: vba, excel, variables, find

My section of code is as follows;

```
Dim Column1 As String
Worksheets("Graph").Activate
Column1 = Cells(1, "P").Value

Dim Column2 As String
Worksheets("Graph").Activate
Column2 = Cells(2, "P").Value

Cells.Find(What:=Column1).Activate
StartP3Column = ActiveCell.Column

Cells.Find(What:=Column2).Activate
StartP4Column = ActiveCell.Column
EndP3Column = StartP4Column - 1

Cells.Find(What:="End Column").Activate
StartEndColumn = ActiveCell.Column
EndP4Column = StartEndColumn - 1
```

I'm trying to make it so the values in P1 and P2 will determine which columns are selected when the macro is run. So in the first 2 `Cell.Find(What:=)` Functions, I want the "Column1" to be picking up the Column1 variable (the value in P1).

When i run the macro, i get the error "Run-Time error: 91. Object variable of with block variable not set" and when i debug, the issue is with line `Cells.Find(What:=Column1).Activate`

Any ideas?

Comment: Can the value be found?  You need to check the return so dim r as range, set r=find(), then check the return, r, if its not found it's nothing.  Then if not nothing r.activate, but only the find of P2 would be activated in this macro.  Also you don't need to activate Graph twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search those data on the sheet `Sheet1`, this will run :

```
Dim wsG As Worksheet
Dim wsS As Worksheet
Dim Rg As Range
Dim Column1 As String
Dim Column2 As String
Set wsG = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graph")
Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

wsG.Activate
Column1 = wsG.Cells(1, "P").Value
Column2 = wsG.Cells(2, "P").Value

Set Rg = wsS.Cells.Find(What:=Column1)
If Not Rg Is Nothing Then
    StartP3Column = Rg.Column
Else
    MsgBox Column1 & " not found in " & wsS.Name
End If

Set Rg = wsS.Cells.Find(What:=Column2)
If Not Rg Is Nothing Then
    StartP4Column = Rg.Column
    EndP3Column = Rg.Column - 1
Else
    MsgBox Column2 & " not found in " & wsS.Name
End If

Set Rg = wsS.Cells.Find(What:="End Column")
If Not Rg Is Nothing Then
    StartEndColumn = Rg.Column
    EndP4Column = Rg.Column - 1
Else
    MsgBox "End Column" & " not found in " & wsS.Name
End If
```

Comment: Hi, the data i'm searching for is on a different worksheet. I've tried editing the your script to look for the values in the other workbook however it hasn't worked and the values for StartP3Column, StartP4Column etc are all "Empty" apart from EndP4Column which is 30.

Comment: @Dullspark : See the edit! ;) You just have to change `Sheet1` to the name of the sheet you are searching into! ;)

Comment: I've done that and the values are still coming up as empty :(

Comment: @Dullspark : I've added a message so that you know if the data isn't found! ;)